# keyup event on input are firing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Enter search text..." />
<input type="submit" id="btnSearch" name="find" value="" />
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {    

$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
    doTheSearch();
});

$("#search").keyup(doTheSearch());

});
```

and

```
function doTheSearch() {
alert("");
var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.read();
};
```

I'm using KendoUI grid with mvc wrappers, not sure if relevant but here is that code also

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<E4.Administrasjon.Models.viewModels.vmUser>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.BrukerID);
    columns.Bound(p => p.navn);

})
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax() // Specify that the data source is of ajax type
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Users_Read", "User")
        .Data("searchData")
    )
    .PageSize(20)
)
.Pageable()    
)
```

The problem is that when the page loads the function doTheSearch() are fired. This should as I try to code only fire when the user enters text or pressing the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invocing the function and not binding it to an event, this:

```
$("#search").keyup(doTheSearch());
```

should be :

```
$("#search").keyup(doTheSearch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#btnSearch").on('click', function () {
    doTheSearch();
});

$("#search").on('keyup', doTheSearch);


function doTheSearch() {
alert("x");
}
```